# How to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Options.OperationalStoreOptions'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identityserver4

I created a aspnet core web application and installed IdentityServer4 and IdentityServer4.EntityFramework packages to use database storage for Client and Resources configuration instead of inMemory. However when I add the ConfigurationDbContext and PersistedGrantDbContext in the services collection as shown in the image below[image: Image of services configuration] 
I get an exception saying "Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Options.OperationalStoreOptions' while attempting to activate 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts.PersistedGrantDbContext'."
as seen in the commandline screenshot below[image: commandline screenshot]

How do I fix the exception being thrown

Comment: Can you clarify why are you registering types manually and not using `services.AddIdentityServer().AddConfigurationStore(builder => ... )` extension method as per documentation?

Comment: When I do not manually I get an error like **No DbContext named 'PersistedGrantDbContext' was found.** And if you look at line 63 I did use the AddConfigurationStore extension method but it throws an error when adding migrations

Comment: From what I can see it should [work out-of-the-box](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Example/blob/master/src/ScottBrady91.IdentityServer4.Example/Startup.cs). Are you sure you are using both `AddOperationalStore` and `AddConfigurationStore` to configure your persistent storage?

Comment: Yes, I am using them both

Comment: Again I do not understand why you are registering the `DbContexts` manually (and effectively registering them twice). Can you clarify? You should **really** just register them one time using `AddOperationalStore` etc, and not using `AddDbContext`.

Comment: Like i said when I register it once I get an error that 'No DbContext named 'PersistedGrantDbContext' was found.'

Comment: @PhathutshedzoKhabubu I had a similar problem and wrapped my whole `ConfigureServices` inside a try catch and `Console.WriteLine` the error. Maybe you can find out more that way

Comment: @moritzg Thanks alot I used the try-catch and was able to solve the issue I posted my answer.

Comment: gettting this same DbContext error. I already have aspnet identity installed, and the documentations is just not covering anything but green field implementation. two days wasted. getting frustrated

Comment: Did you try the solution below @NathanTregillus

Comment: not yet. the whole project got trashed because the integrating company said they were using Oauth2, but in reality they had thier own custom grown identity check... back to the drawing board.

Comment: Ohhh thats sad. If you ever need any assistance just shout. I have become kinda good at identityServer4 now. Even used it with Angular4

Comment: `.AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyName));
            })`  at 
<https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_entityframework.html>  might fix this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to solve this issue**

Firstly I removed the DbContexts that I was adding manually which is from line 49 to 53, in the first screenshot.
Secondly I made a mistake when adding the `.AddSigningCredentials()` loading the certificate I am supposed to use the `IHostingEnvironment` to get the ContentRootPath to my certificate. Therefore change `.AddSigningCredentials(..)` to:

```
.AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath,
                "sample-cert.pfx"), "password")
```

Add thats how I solved the exception being thrown and processed the migrations I wanted to.

Answer (score 7):

I have resole this error by adding below lines in StartUp.cs file

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var storeOptions = new ConfigurationStoreOptions();
        services.AddSingleton(storeOptions);
     }
```

Hope that will helps you also

Comment: This did nothing for me.